# Does she have to wait for a response card?

Tags: uno

Do people have to wait and see if their friend has a response card to a draw 2 in the game uno?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the basic game of uno there is no response card to a draw 2/4, skip or reverse. Anything that allows you to respond is a house rule so the only response to a draw 2/4 is to draw that cards and a skip is to miss the turn.

If you are playing by house rules then it depends on the house rules and I would think the person would either have to draw the cards or play a response card.